# Why does my tar file extraction to destination throw an error?

Tags: linux, tar

I am trying to extract the tar.gz folder into a new destination, but it throws the following error? How can I do the changes in Linux command to extract those folder.

```
$ tar -zxvf IUS17.05_g311_lnx86_GPLV3_N20170504.tar.gz /cad/local/apps/cadence/xcelium
tar: /cad/local/apps/cadence/xcelium: Not found in archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is that you, by saying

```
tar -xf archive.tar path
```

is asking to extract `path` from `archive.tar`.  When `path` is not found in `archive.tar`, you get a `Not found in archive` error.

The option that you should have used is `-C path` which, while extracting, sets the destination directory for the files in the archive.

The full command line in your case:

```
tar -zxvf IUS17.05_g311_lnx86_GPLV3_N20170504.tar.gz -C /cad/local/apps/cadence/xcelium
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **-C** option to define the destination

```
tar -zxvf IUS17.05_g311_lnx86_GPLV3_N20170504.tar.gz -C /cad/local/apps/cadence/xcelium
```

**Note: make sure your have the write privilege on the destination directory**